# How to construct the sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence

I am trying to solve the following problem-
Let $A$ be a non empty and compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$. If $a$ is not in $A$ then show that there exists a real number $\theta>0$ such that $\left\lVert x-a\right\rVert\geq\theta$ for all $x\in A$

My attempt- Suppose not, then, $\exists$ $x’\in A$ s.t. $\forall$ $\theta>0$ we have 
$$\left\lVert x-a\right\rVert <\theta$$

Now if I can construct a sequence $x_n$ such that $x_n$ $\in A$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_n$ converges to $a$ then I can say that since $A$ is compact $a$ $\in$ $A$ which is a contradiction and so I’d be done, but I am unable to construct the sequence which satisfies the above conditions so can someone please provide with the method to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

You want to prove that
if $a$ is not in $A$ then

$$(\exists \theta>0)\;  : \; (\forall x\in A)\;\;  ||x-a||\ge \theta$$

as you done, assume

$$(\forall \theta>0) \; (\exists x_{\theta}\in A)\; : $$
$$\;\;||x_{\theta}-a||\le \theta$$

in particular,
$$(\forall n \in \Bbb N)\;\; (\exists x_n\in A) \;\; : $$
$$\;\; ||x_n-a||<\frac 1n$$

Comment: Yup this is the required sequence that I couldn’t cone up with, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Going on with the assumption from the attempt:

For each $n$ pick $x_n \in A$ with $d(x_n,a) < \frac1n$ and by compactness of $A$ we have some $a_0 \in A$ and a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k} \to a_0 \,(k \to \infty)$. Now for each $\varepsilon>0$ you pick, you can reason that $d(a,a_0) < \varepsilon)$ via the triangle inequality. This implies that $a=a_0$ a contradiction as $a \notin A$ and $a_0 \in A$.

Comment: I see that you use the bolzano theorem, this is a nice answer as well, thanks

Comment: @user601297 Yoi don't really need the compactness; the closedness of $A$ is enough, actually.

Comment: Yes I do see that.